# Spark Custom Aggregator -- register and invoke through PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

According to various docs, to write a custom Aggregator in Spark it must be written in Java/Scala.

https://medium.com/swlh/apache-spark-3-0-remarkable-improvements-in-custom-aggregation-41dbaf725903

I have built and compiled a test implementation of a custom aggregator, but would now like to register and invoke it through PySpark and SparkSQL.

I tried spark.udf.registerJavaUDAF ... but that seems only to work with the older style UDAF functions not the new Aggregators.

How can I register a new Aggregator function written in Java through PySpark if at all possible? (I know how to pass the JAR to spark-submit etc the problem is the registration call).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the correct approach is, but I was able to get the following to work.

In your Java class that extends `Aggregator`:

```java
// This is assumed to be part of: com.example.java.udaf
// MyUdaf is the class that extends Aggregator
// I'm using Encoders.LONG() as an example, change this as needed
// Change the registered Spark SQL name, `myUdaf`, as needed
// Note that if you don't want to hardcode the "myUdaf" string, you can pass that in too.

// Expose UDAF registration
// This function is necessary for Python utilization
public static void register(SparkSession spark) {
    spark.udf().register("myUdaf", functions.udaf(new MyUdaf(), Encoders.LONG()));
}
```

Then in Python:

```py
udaf_jar_path = "..."

# Running in standalone mode
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("udaf_demo")\
    .config("spark.jars", udaf_jar_path)\
    .master("local[*]")\
    .getOrCreate()

# Register using registration function provided by Java class
spark.sparkContext._jvm.com.example.java.udaf.MyUdaf.register(_spark._jsparkSession)
```

As a bonus, you can use this same registration function in Java:

```java
// Running in standalone mode
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .master("local[*]")
        .appName("udaf_demo")
        .getOrCreate();

register(spark);
```

Then you should be able to use this directly in Spark SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    col0
    , myUdaf(col1)
FROM some_table
GROUP BY 1
```

I tested this with a simple summation and it worked reasonably well. For summing 1M numbers, the Python version was ~150ms slower than the Java one (local testing using standalone mode, with both run directly within my IDEs). Compared to the built-in sum it was about half a second slower.

An alternative approach is to use Spark native functions. I haven't directly used this approach; however, I have used the [spark-alchemy](https://github.com/swoop-inc/spark-alchemy) library which does. See their repo for more details.